# Implicitly call parent constructors

Tags: c#

I have a set of classes where my base has a constructor that takes a configuration object and handles transferring the values to its properties.

```
abstract class A { public A(ObjType MyObj){} } 
abstract class B : A {}
class C : A {}
class D : B {}
class E : B {}
```

Is it possible to implicitly call a non-default base constructor from child classes or would I need to explicitly implement the signature up the chain to do it via constructors?

```
abstract class A { public A(ObjType MyObj){} } 
abstract class B : A { public A(ObjType MyObj) : base(MyObj){} }
class C : A { public A(ObjType MyObj) : base(MyObj){} }
class D : B { public A(ObjType MyObj) : base(MyObj){} }
class E : B { public A(ObjType MyObj) : base(MyObj){} }
```

If that is the case, is it better to just implement a method in the base then have my factory immediately call the method after creating the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Implicitly*?  No, constructors are not inherited.  Your class may *explicitly* call it's parent's constructor.  But if you want your class to have the same constructor signatures as the parent class's, you must implement them.

For example:

```
public class A
{
    public A(int someNumber)
    {
    }
}

// This will not compile becase A doesn't have a default constructor and B 
// doesn't inherit A's constructors.
public class B : A
{
}
```

To make this work you'd have to explicitly declare the constructors you want B to have, and have them call A's constructors explicitly (unless A has a default constructor of course).

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(int someNumber) : base(someNumber)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That was what I (modestly) feared.  I think I'll go the helper-method route.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to call a non-default base constructor *implicitly*, you have to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly implement it up the chain. Also, importantly, in your original code, you will not be able to call a `new B()`, since `A` does not have a default constructor, and `B` does not call `A`'s constructor that has an arg.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, was omitting default constructor for brevity.