# Call Parent Constructor via Child's Implementation

Tags: c++

Book inherits LibraryItem

```
class Book : public LibraryItem {
```

Here is my attempt at using the constructor in the parent class.

```
Book::Book(std::string title, std::string callNumber, std::string publisher, std::string location, int year, std::string authors, std::string ISBN, std::string subject, std::string edition) {
    LibrayItem(title, callNumber, publisher, location, 'B', year);
    this->authors = authors;
    this->ISBN = ISBN;
    this->subject = subject;
    this->edition = edition;
}
```

g++ gives me:

> LibraryItem.cpp: In constructor ‘Book::Book(std::string, std::string,
>   std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string,
>   std::string)’: LibraryItem.cpp:72:62: error: ‘LibrayItem’ was not
>   declared in this scope   LibrayItem(title, callNumber, publisher,
>   location, 'B', year);

So then I searched and found [Implicitly call parent constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485687/implicitly-call-parent-constructors). I tried:

```
Book::Book(std::string title, std::string callNumber, std::string publisher, std::string location, int year, std::string authors, std::string ISBN, std::string subject, std::string edition) : LibrayItem(title, callNumber, publisher, location, 'B', year) {
    [...]
}
```

g++ gives me:

> LibraryItem.cpp: In
>   constructor ‘Book::Book(std::string, std::string, std::string,
>   std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string,
>   std::string)’: LibraryItem.cpp:71:193: error: class ‘Book’ does not
>   have any field named ‘LibrayItem’  Book::Book(std::string title,
>   std::string callNumber, std::string publisher, std::string location,
>   int year, std::string authors, std::string ISBN, std::string subject,
>   std::string edition) : LibrayItem(title, callNumber, publisher,
>   location, 'B', year) {

I'm at a loss, I checked my header file for Book and it does inherit LibraryItem publicly, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
class Book : public LibraryItem {
    private:
        [...]
    public:
        Book();
        Book(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class LibraryItem
{
    public:
        LibraryItem(int) {}
};

class Book
    : public LibraryItem
{
    public:
        Book(int)
            : LibraryItem(0)
        {}
};
```

Works fine, but you have a typo in your code that most likely causes this problem:

```
: LibrayItem(title, callNumber, publisher, location, 'B', year) {
```

which should be

```
: LibraryItem(title, callNumber, publisher, location, 'B', year) {
```

Comment: Why do those two lines look identical?

Comment: @WhozCraig Notice the missing `r` in `Library`

Answer (score 0):

I think in declaration you said it is Libra***r***yItem is base class but here

```
Book::Book(std::string title, std::string callNumber, std::string publisher, std::string location, int year, std::string authors, std::string ISBN, std::string subject, std::string edition) : LibrayItem(title, callNumber, publisher, location, 'B', year) {
    [...]
}
```

you are using LibrayItem missing **r** . This could be the problem.